# AWS - Calling API using API gateway to Lambda using binary file and input parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, gateway

Can anyone help me with the configuration i need to do in API gateway to get a image file and some input param to lambda functions?
E.g. i want to upload image to S3 from lambda and write the metadata in dynamo db.
User can call api with image and metadata (e.g. customer id, mobile number).

For image file, i have added mapping template in integration as 
"content" : "$input.body"
and Content-Type as application/png

API gateway settings[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovl6a.png)

But i can't figure out how to map the query param for the meta data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

See documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference

You can map request parameter via

> `$input.params(x)`
>   Returns the value of a method request parameter from the path, query string, or header value (searched in that order), given a parameter name string x.